# How to access this in javascript/typescript event callback, while retaining ability to removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript, typescript, addeventlistener

I seem to be in a catch-22 right now, where I want to attach an event listener within a javascript/typescript object (and retain access to `this` in my callback function), but I need to remove said event listener as well.  Normally, setting up such a callback (where one has access to `this`) uses anonymous functions, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
  property = 'testing...';

  constructor(public element: HTMLElement) {}      

  attachListener() {
    this.element.addEventListener(
      'mouseover',
      () => { console.log(this.property); }
    );
  }

  removeListener() {
    this.element.removeEventListener(
      'mouseover',
      PROBLEM!
    )
  }
}
```

Obviously this wont work, as my callback is anonymous, thus I don't have the ability to remove it.  In my case, this would be the only `mouseover` event, so I'd be fine with removing *all* attached listeners, but haven't found a way to do that either.  Any thoughts on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an anonymous function make the handler a class method

```
class MyClass {
  property = 'testing...';

  constructor(public element: HTMLElement) {
     this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this)
  }


  handleMouseOver(event) {
    console.log(this.property)
  }

  attachListener() {
    this.element.addEventListener(
      'mouseover',
      this.handleMouseOver
    );
  }

  removeListener() {
    this.element.removeEventListener(
      'mouseover',
      this.handleMouseOver
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It appears I was over thinking things (though I swear I had an issue in the past with passing the class method directly to an event listener).  In my actual code I was simply using the anonymous function to call `this.someMethod()` so this worked great!

Comment: Ahh... probably have to put `this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this)` in constructor. Will update in answer

Comment: Now the `console.log(this.property)` does not work any more